# MySQL syntax error in Trigger IF statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm very new to SQL and am having issues with syntax in my triggers. I am trying to set a minimum rating of 1 and a maximum rating of 5 for horses after a race. The problem seems to be with the IF statement.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_rating
AFTER insert on stats
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (new.rating > 5) THEN
    SET new.rating = 5
    ELSEIF (new.rating < 1) THEN
    SET new.rating = 1
     END IF;
END; //
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ERROR 1362 (HY000): Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger

This is the error. It means you can't use `SET` to change any of the values of the row you are inserting, because in an `AFTER INSERT` trigger, the row has already been inserted. You would have to do this in a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger for this to work.

You should read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html which says:

> Such a SET statement has no effect in an AFTER trigger because the row change will have already occurred.

If I correct this and change it to a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, I get this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ELSEIF (new.rating < 1) THEN ...

I notice you did not end the `SET` statement with a semicolon. This is necessary to terminate every statement in the trigger, including `SET` statements.

Here's the trigger that works:

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_rating BEFORE insert on stats
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     IF (new.rating > 5) THEN
         SET new.rating = 5;
     ELSEIF (new.rating < 1) THEN
         SET new.rating = 1;
     END IF;
END
```